# unramified extension of local field

Tags: number-theory

I'm reading a proof, in which there is a statement involving local field. I don't know where it comes from. Can anyone provide me some facts about local field that give this statement please?

Give $K'/K$ is an unramified extension of local fields, and $u'$ is in $R'^$ ($R'$ is the valuation ring of $K'$). It said: Since $K'/K$ is unramified, we can find $u \in K$ with $u/u' \in R'^*$.

Comment: Presumably $u'\in R'$, not necessarily in $R'^*$?

Comment: $u' \in R'$. I edited the confusion.

Comment: Dear @user1412, No, you still have that $u^\prime$ is a unit in $R^\prime$, but that's seemingly not what you want to assume since in that case you can take $u=1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because $K^\prime/K$ is unramified, if $\pi\in R$ is a uniformizer, it is also a uniformizer in $R^\prime$. Now, if $u^\prime\in R^\prime$, this means that we can write $u^\prime=\pi^m v^\prime$ with $m\geq 0$ and $v^\prime\in(R^\prime)^\times$. Taking $u=\pi^m\in K$, we find that $u/u^\prime=v^\prime\in(R^\prime)^\times$.